# What dll's are necessary to use php_pdo_sqlsrv without installing MS SQL driver

Tags: php, sql-server, dll, pdo, sqlsrv

I'm running PHP7.4 VC15 x64 TS on Windows10 64bit.

What DLLs do I need to put beneath php.exe to be able to connect to a MS SQL Server via php_pdo_sqlsrv.
PHP is not complaining directly after starting php.exe, but on the pdo-connect statement with the error "Could not load driver".

The solution was to install the SQL Server Driver from MS. But I have a case where I have to use just plain DLLs copy. I could not track down which DLLs are necessary.

A list of DLLs would be very nice OR a way of how to find out which DLLs are necessary.

Comment: Dont even think this! Install what is suggested because if you dont it wont work properly

Comment: Where do you think those DLLs come from exactly? From the driver software. But simply copy/pasting them is unlikely to work correctly - there's usually more to it than that (e.g. configuration, registrations etc). But what case could there be where you can't install the driver? If you aren't able to install it yourself due to permissions,  ask the system administrator to do it for you. If they won't for some reason, then find somewhere else to host your software which is more amenable.

Comment: @ADyson, Thx for the reply. Ok, let me rephrase this. How can I find out what the driver software installer is doing underneath?

Comment: Why do you need to know? What is stopping you from just installing the driver or asking someone to do it for you?

Comment: I need to distribute the php application to people on our network. And none of them has administrative privileges and the system administrators do not offer any support.

Comment: Then you need to engage with the system administrators and get them to support what you are doing (assuming it's legitimate). Even if you discover what the installer does, the actions it performs will still require admin privileges.

Comment: @ADyson, so you're telling me: "It's not possible to distribute and run a PHP application which requires a MS SQL-Server connection without having admin rights (at least once, for the installation).". If this holds true, please add an answer and I'll accept it. Even this is a total design flaw in my opinion.

Comment: This is nothing to do with PHP really. Installing system-level stuff such as drivers on windows requires admin rights. You'd have the same issue for any application, written in any language, which required such drivers. Complain to Microsoft if you think that's a problem, but there are good reasons why they have massively tightened up this kind of security stuff in recent years.

Comment: You could try to use the PHP ODBC drivers instead, which are likely to be already present, although you may still need to set something in php.ini (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php and linked pages for some details).

Comment: Alternatively, could you run your application as a web application on a single server, instead of distributing it to multiple network users? It depends what it does, I suppose.

Comment: +1 For the ODBC driver tip. Despite that you're of course right, that the driver installation is independent from PHP. I just mentioned that because it's currently PHP-related in my environment. But my point seems still valid to any portable application. I really do think that "no DB-connections without admin rights" is a flaw, since every other DB vendor offers exactly that possibility, but MS is not going to change that though.